# Is it possible to get size of a text or image object in inches using fabricjs?

Tags: canvas, text, size, fabricjs

I am using fabricjs for a product designer. I need to get objects size in inches. Is it possible, if yes then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't get it from FabricJS directly.
For this, you have to convert it by using your monitor DPI. Generally DPI is 96 for devices, but you can get it by javascript too. For this add below code to your page -

```
<div id='wdm_dpi_div' style='height: 1in; left: -100%; position: absolute; top: -100%; width: 1in;'></div>

<script> 
var dpi_x = document.getElementById('wdm_dpi_div').offsetWidth;
var dpi_y = document.getElementById('wdm_dpi_div').offsetHeight;
// if your objects height in pixel is obj_height = 480 then
var obj_height_in_inch = obj_height/dpi_y;
// if your objects width in pixel is obj_width = 672 then
var obj_width_in_inch = obj_width/dpi_x;
</script>
```

But it is better to convert pixel to inch by constant DPI 96.